# Concealing ~ in texvim + conceal

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex, conceal

I tried

```
syn match texStatement '\\\[' contained conceal cchar=⟦                         
syn match texStatement '\\\]' contained conceal cchar=⟧                         
syn match texStatement '\\~' contained conceal cchar=X
```

The last line did not work, and even if I did, how do I use   (space) rather than X.

Comment: Try `'\\\~'` based on `:help /~`

Comment: Can you rephrase the last sentence? I guess you mean to write "how do I use a space rather than X?", that is, that the dangling 1 was supposed to be a question mark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line does not work because you need to escape tilde. To use a space instead of X, you can simply write a space. So, this should work:

```
syntax match texStatement '\\\~' contained conceal cchar=
```

Notice that the last character above is a space character!